# Like I versus Like me

Tags: grammar

My friend and I got into an argument about English grammar, so I was hoping maybe you could help us out. Okay so we want to know if the following part of the sentence is correct, "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like I" rather than "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like me". I have already provided many sources to my friend showing that the first way is a formal and a grammatically correct way, however he wants an answer with this specific part of the sentence.

Please help us out

Thank you

Comment: At the moment the question is flawed because, "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like I/me" is not a complete sentence. Examples of complete sentences:- "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like I do are happy." -- "I respect people who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like me." Both are correct but for different reasons.

Comment: I realize this is an old question but I want to add my 2 cents. The truth is "like I" is the correct (and the only correct) way however this is the problem with natural languages - if enough ignorants make the same mistake that mistake becomes the norm and the correct way is then considered "obsolete"/"artificial"/etc...

Answer (score 8):

*Like* acts as a preposition, and its object takes the objective case if it is capable of encoding case.

> People like me who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled ...
>   People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like me ...

*Like I* occurs only when *I* is not the object of the preposition but merely the subject of a clause which is the object of a preposition.

> People who are satisfied like I am ...
>    People who feel self-fulfilled like I do ...

In formal registers, however, you should be using *as* here, rather than *like*.

> People who are satisfied, as I am ...
>    People who feel self-fulfilled, as I do ...

Comment: So which one uses the correct like I or like me. The first one "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like I would focus on the content rather than themselves." Or the second version "People who are satisfied and feel self-fulfilled like me would focus on the content rather than themselves."

Comment: @Arthur: Have you read the answer? This is really the perfect answer, would buy again, 1+.

Comment: @arthur In OP's example *I* is not the subject of a verb, so it must be *me*

Answer (score -2):

The definitive answer, from an [English language corpus](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like%20me.,like%20I.&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1;,like%20me%20.;,c0;.t1;,like%20I.;,c0) is very clear: your friend is wrong.  *like me.* is at least 1000 times more prevalent than *like I.*

So where did your friend get his crazy ideas from?

Very roughly speaking, the rule in "natural" English is that you only use *I* before a verb.  In other situations, revert to *me*.

> It's **me**!  **I**'m over here!
>
> He is taller than **me**.
>
> He is taller than **I** am.
>
> One day, **me** and my dog went for a walk.
>
> **I** went for a walk with my dog.

In formal contexts, the influence of 18th century Latin-influenced grammarians has crept in, and there are still authorities who advise people to write like this:

> It is **I**!

(never *It's I*, because *It's* would be sloppy and vulgar)

> He is taller than **I**.

(many people will tell you that this is the correct because *taller than I* is an abbreviation for *taller than I am*)

> My dog and **I** went for a walk.

(never *I and my dog*, because it would be rude to put yourself before your dog, apparently)

You can probably tell that I don't think much of this version of English grammar.  But there you have it.

So it may be that one of these Latin-freaks has advised your friend to use *like I.*  Or maybe your friend has taken the justification for writing *He is taller than I.*, and applied it to *He is tall, like I.*  Well ... at least he's trying to apply the rules consistently.

Comment: 'Tis I is an archaic alternative to It is I.

Comment: In your ngram you placed a full-stop after the entries thus creating a false result. Here is what the graph should actually look like https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=like+me%2Clike+I&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20me%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clike%20I%3B%2Cc0  -- In fact it is the context that decides which is correct at any given time. See the examples in my comment under the question.